# ProGuard, How can I hide all logs while obfuscating the code and not break my app?

Tags: android, proguard

I have an app that I am trying to clean and protect with ProGuard, I want to Obfuscate to protected from Reverse engineering, I know that It can still be Decompiled but harder to read, I also want to remove all logs from log cat because there are many logs that are sensitive in private information and I don't want anyone to read that. So I have done something but It destroys my app's functionality completely. How can I make it work?

Here is my code

```
-dontoptimize


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

-libraryjars /myexta.jar
-libraryjars /commons-codec-1.8.jar
-libraryjars /lib.jar


-keep public class com.thejs.app.** {
  public protected *;
}

-keep public class com.my.load.** {
  public protected *;
}
```

I have Libraries that I use, How can ProGuard keep all and clean it? When I launch the app the Main activity works, all subactivities crash and don't work.

---

As I have deeply analyzed the logs It appears that proguard actually breaks all libraries and most classes, The app just can't find it. When I export it without ProGuard it's perfect and there are no issues. What I want to do is two things

1.Obfuscate
2.Remove Entire App's Logging from the log cat.

I am getting stuck in here,I use

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static *** d(...);
        public static *** v(...);
        public static *** i(...);
    }
```

to delete logs,

Somehow I have never got it to work It always breaks my app, I only need this two things. Shrink is useless and problematic since My app is really small. How can I get it to work?

more info:

Logcat

```
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798): Activity com.thejs.app.Myactivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@309d2738 that was originally added here
06-24 14:49:58.270: E/MP3AudioPlayer(1798): Native libs libffmpeg.so not exists!
06-24 14:49:58.540: E/MP3AudioPlayer(1798): Native libs libffmpeg.so not exists!
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:259)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at com.thejs.app.Myactivity.onPreExecute(Unknown Source)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at com.thejs.app.Myactivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
06-24 14:49:58.750: E/WindowManager(1798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 14:50:06.070: E/dalvikvm(1798): Class lookup Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; attempted while exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; pending
06-24 14:50:06.080: E/dalvikvm(1798): VM aborting
06-24 14:50:06.360: E/dalvikvm(491): Killing existing arm process with pid 1798
```

Comment: that looks right, when you say it `breaks my app`, what does that mean?  do you have error messages or anything?

Comment: Sure I will be as detailed as I can possible, I have updated my Question, Breaks my app means that all my activities crash and don't work, Only one activity works and it's the first one. Thanks